# Is there a way to update parameters as each scheduled flow run?

Tags: prefect

I'm trying to find a way to update the parameters begin used for each iteration of a schedule flow.

For example, say I have a flow that's schedule to run once every Monday for a year. For the first Monday the flow needs to run with a parameter of say 5. The next Monday needs to be ran with a parameter of 7 etc. The parameter needed for each weeks' run would change by a constant number.

Based on the docs, it looks like I could create a clock with the corresponding parameter for each run but that seems excessive for flows that are schedule for many runs.

Is there a simpler way of doing this in Prefect?

Comment: Adding some code to the question would increase the chances of getting an answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you want to encapsulate some form of business logic into your `Parameter` calculation, which is a great use case for adding a new `Task` to your Flow:

```py
import prefect
from prefect import task, Flow, Parameter


varying_param = Parameter("param", default=None) # none as the default

@task(name="Varying Parameter")
def param_calculation(p):
    time = prefect.context.scheduled_start_time 

    # if a value was provided, use it
    if p is not None:
        return p
    
    # do some calculations to decide what value is appropriate
    # and return it


with Flow("Minimal example") as flow:
    param_value = param_calculation(varying_param)
    # now use this value in downstream tasks
```